# UILabel inside of UIStackView has 0 height, although it has content

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout

I have `UIView` subclass `UIViewA`. It contains another view `UIViewB` set from code somewhere using dependency injection.

```
class UIViewA {
    var viewB: UIViewB { // injected
        substitudeView()
        attachWithConstraints()
    }
    func chargeWithContent(_ some: Some) {
        viewB.chargeWithContent(some)
    }
}

class UIViewB {
    func chargeWithContent(_ some: Some) {
        label1.text = some.text1
        label2.text = some.text2
    }
}
```

`UIViewB` has `UIStackView` with 2 labels.

With this scenario, everything works fine.

But if I want to have different views depending on type of Some, I have some issues. So with

```
class UIViewA {
    var selectedView: UIViewBOrCProtocol! {
        substitudeView()
        attachWithConstraints()
    }

    var viewB: UIViewB // injected
    var viewC: UIViewC // injected
    func chargeWithContent(_ some: Some) {
        if sekectedView == nil {
            if some.isB {
                selectedView = viewB
            } else {
                selectedView = viewC
            }
        }

        viewB.chargeWithContent(some)
    }
}

class UIViewB {
    func chargeWithContent(_ some: Some) {
        label1.text = some.text1
        label2.text = some.text2
    }
}
```

First label has 0 height, even though it has content to show. Any ideas what can be wrong?

`attachWithConstraints` looks like this:

```
topView.addSubview(header)
header.snp.makeConstraints { $0.edges.equalTo(self.topView) }
```

It basically attaches all the sides to superview.

First implementation works just fine, so I wouldn't think that the issue is with constraints

Comment: It's probably a constraint issue. You should give your implementation of `attachWithConstraints`

Comment: @adriencog, updated question